# Why am i not able to see "Closure" in chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript, closures, google-chrome-devtools

BTW this is the chunk i have used to check:

```
function outerFunction () {
  const outer = `I see the outer variable!`
  function innerFunction() {
    console.log(outer)
  }
  return innerFunction
}
outerFunction()();
```

Do i need to enable something in settings or any extension is required or whatever. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When are you trying to call `debugger` to check it? I can see it just fine inside `innerFunction`

Comment: Please tell us where you are looking in the devtools, maybe post a screenshot.

Comment: I have put debugger on innerFunction and on console to check what does outer var gets as a value.